# Running REST service from Intellij with Maven, Jersey and Tomcat 8

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run an example for a REST service using Ubuntu 16.04, Oracle Java 8, Intellij with Maven, Jersey and Tomcat 8. I'm following the tutorial that can be found here https://medium.com/@jamsesso/starting-out-with-jersey-apache-tomcat-using-intellij-6338d93ffd40#.heb2u4ros. The example is using Tomcat 7 while I'm using Tomcat 8. When I run the code which sends me to `http://localhost:8080/` (but I think  it should be `http://localhost:8080/hello` I've tried it and it gives me a `404` also) I don't get any warnings from Intellij but I get
 `HTTP Status 404 -type Status report message description The requested resource is not available. Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 (Ubuntu)` in the web browser. Starting the Tomcat server from command line works fine and gives me the welcome message. I've gone through all the similar questions I can find on stackoverflow but I haven't been able to solve the problem. I would be very happy for any suggestions on what is wrong with my code.

My code is the following.

```
web.xml
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Example API</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Example API</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

_

```
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>RESTServer</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

_

```
package com.example.jersey;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorld {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Output from Intellij

```
/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/catalina.sh run
[2016-07-10 08:17:15,670] Artifact RESTServer:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 (Ubuntu)
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jul 6 2016 11:49:29 UTC
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.32.0
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            4.4.0-28-generic
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_91-b14
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/mikael/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/system/tomcat/Unnamed_RESTServer_2
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat8
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/mikael/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/system/tomcat/Unnamed_RESTServer_2/conf/logging.properties
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat8/endorsed
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/mikael/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/system/tomcat/Unnamed_RESTServer_2
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/mikael/.IntelliJIdea2016.1/system/tomcat/Unnamed_RESTServer_2/temp
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:17 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1586 ms
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 (Ubuntu)
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 188 ms
Connected to server
[2016-07-10 08:17:18,307] Artifact RESTServer:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Jul 10, 2016 8:17:19 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2016-07-10 08:17:19,467] Artifact RESTServer:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2016-07-10 08:17:19,468] Artifact RESTServer:war exploded: Deploy took 1,161 milliseconds
```

Comment: Your app should be under /RESTServer. And since the resource is under /hello, inside this app, the URL should be /RESTServer/hello

Comment: @JBNizet I tried `http://localhost:8080/RESTServer/hello` but I still get the `404`.

Comment: hope your class package com.example.jersey is within the folder structure RESTServer/src/main/java ?

Comment: @Sampada Yes my folder structure is RESTServer/src/main/java/com.example.jersey/HelloWorld.java

Comment: I still can't get this to work. Is there a log that explains what causes the `HTTP Status 404 -type Status report message description The requested resource is not available. Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 (Ubuntu)`? Like what resource that is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this working. The main issue was the difference in Servlet version and Jersey version that the example uses and what I was able to use. The example is using Servlet 3.0 while I'm using 3.1. I might be wrong here but I think that Servlet 3.1 forces me to use Jersey 2. Both these differences means that the `web.xml` and the `pom.xml` files needs to reflect these changes. I've posted my updated `web.xml` and `pom.xml` below.

```
web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Example API</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.jersey</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Example API</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

-

```
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>stack</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>stack</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <name>Stack</name>
</project>
```